# Select total counts from a column

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

How to fetch data in  column1 and display it on textview but for example,

`this is my column1`

```
bacon
hotdog
fries
bacon
bacon
hotdog
```

and i want to show it on my textview like this or something like this

```
bacon  (3)
hotdog (2)
fries
```

Answer (score 2):

1.Select your data like this:

```
SELECT column1, count(column1) 
FROM mytable 
GROUP BY column1 
ORDER BY count(column1) DESC;
```

2. Write your response in to a string (or StringBuilder if you need to handle many Strings)
3. Pass this string to your Textview

Comment: Thanks man, I will try this later.